# Add string if the Pandas cell has a specific symbol

Tags: python, pandas, string, replace, contains

I have a Pandas dataframe `df` as follows:

```py
ID    stringColumn
0     "string1"
1     string2
2     string "3"
3     string4"
```

Here's what I need:

```py
ID    stringColumn
0     \"string1\"
1     string2
2     string \"3\"
3     string4\"
```

I've tried using

```
df['stringColumn'].str.contains(r'"')
```

But I could not get far. How can I change the values?

Comment: Please provide the output of `df.to_dict('list')` to have a non ambiguous input. You might want `df['stringColumn'].str.replace('"', '\\"', regex=False)`

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df['stringColumn'] = df['stringColumn'].str.replace(r'"', r'\"', regex=True)
```